# What is the best way to refresh webview in xamarin.forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I Handled webview success loading as the following :

```
 void WebOnEndNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Result!=WebNavigationResult.Success)
        {
           //show message ... click on the button to retry

        }

    }
```

> Here is event Refresh button :

```
  void Refresh_Click(object Sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        webview.Source = (webview.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url;
    }
```

When I connect to the internet an click on the refresh button, Reloading webview success but on `WebOnEndNavigating eventHandler` WebNavigationResult is failed
what is the correct way to reload webview on Xamarin.Forms